# Understanding how OpenGL blending works

Tags: opengl, blending

I am attempting to understand how OpenGL (ES) blending works. I am finding it difficult to understand the documentation and how the results of [glBlendFunc](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glBlendFunc.xml) and [glBlendEquation](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glBlendEquation.xml) effect the final pixel that is written.

Do the source and destination out of glBlendFunc get added together with GL_FUNC_ADD by default?

This seems wrong because "basic" blending of GL_ONE, GL_ONE would output 2,2,2,2 then (Source giving 1,1,1,1 and dest giving 1,1,1,1).

I have written the following pseudo-code, what have I got wrong?

```
struct colour {
    float r, g, b, a;
};

colour blend_factor( GLenum factor, 
    colour source,
    colour destination,
    colour blend_colour ) {

    colour colour_factor;
    float i = min( source.a, 1 - destination.a );

    // From http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glBlendFunc.xml
    switch( factor ) {
        case GL_ZERO: colour_factor = { 0, 0, 0, 0 }; break;
        case GL_ONE: colour_factor = { 1, 1, 1, 1 }; break;
        case GL_SRC_COLOR: colour_factor = source; break;
        case GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_COLOR: colour_factor = { 1 - source.r, 1 - source.g, 1 - source.b, 1 - source.a }; break;
        // ...
    }

    return colour_factor;
}

colour blend( colour & source, 
    colour destination, 
    GLenum source_factor, // from glBlendFunc
    GLenum destination_factor, // from glBlendFunc
    colour blend_colour, // from glBlendColor
    GLenum blend_equation // from glBlendEquation
    ) {

    colour source_colour = blend_factor( source_factor, source, destination, blend_colour );
    colour destination_colour = blend_factor( destination_factor, source, destination, blend_colour );
    colour output;

    // From http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glBlendEquation.xml
    switch( blend_equation ) {
        case GL_FUNC_ADD: output = add( mul( source, source_colour ), mul( destination, destination_colour ) );
        case GL_FUNC_SUBTRACT: output = sub( mul( source, source_colour ), mul( destination, destination_colour ) );
        case GL_FUNC_REVERSE_SUBTRACT: output = sub( mul( destination, destination_colour ), mul( source, source_colour ) );
    }

    return output;
}



void do_pixel() {

    colour final_colour;

    // Blending
    if( enable_blending ) {

        final_colour = blend( current_colour_output, framebuffer[ pixel ], ... );
    } else {

        final_colour = current_colour_output;
    }

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: "Do the source and destination out of glBlendFunc get added together with GL_FUNC_ADD by default?" Are you really asking if the `GL_FUNC_ADD` function actually *adds things*?

Comment: maybe he's just asking if  `ADD`  is the default, and yes it is ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
case GL_FUNC_ADD: output = add( source_colour, destination_colour )
```

This is where you've gone wrong. The source and destination factors are multiplied into the source and destination colors, *then* added together. The [OpenGL Wiki article on blending](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Blending#Blend_Equations) goes into greater detail on this matter.

Comment: Here's a handy visual to with that: http://i.stack.imgur.com/i2IAC.jpg